# Can't Import org.Json on Online Editor

Tags: java, json

I'm Solving a question on CoderByte of fetching the data from the api.
I've solved on VS Code and I'm getting the perfect answer. But when I copy paste the code on online editor of CodeByte
it giving me error `error: package org.json does not exist import org.json.JSONArray;`
I Can't Import Json Jar file on Online Editor

Answer (score 1):

Your online solution runs in the environment of the server that provides the environment. Obviously, the specified jar is not available on that server.

Comment: Yeah I know. But what to do now. How could I solve this